# cd .. command does not work with gcloud compute ssh while other basic commands (such as pwd) do work. Why?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform

I have a running instance `my-instance` running on google-cloud. I run the following code on my local machine:

```
gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command 'pwd'
gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command 'cd ..'
gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command 'pwd'
```

my output is:

```
/home/pal
/home/pal
```

My expectation is:

```
/home/pal
/home
```

It seems that `cd ..` is not working. Why is it? It is surprising for me especially that `pwd` works as shown above. How can I solve the issue?

---

I used this page as source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh

Comment: When you run `cd` in a new shell, the changed directory only lives as long as the shell does. Shell is started -> shell successfully runs `cd ..` -> she shell exits -> the parent process is still in whatever directory it was in before. So `cd ..` *works perfectly well*; it just doesn't impact completely separate commands' behavior.

Comment: Try `gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command 'cd .. && pwd'`

Comment: This isn't gcloud-specific in any way, btw -- you'd have the same behavior with any other `ssh somehost 'cd ..'` command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958954/why-would-ssh-commands-through-putty-work-differently-to-those-via-phps-phpsecl for an example of the same issue being hit by someone else (using a completely different toolkit -- PHP's ssh client library instead of gcloud tools).

Comment: `gcloud compute ssh my-instance --command 'cd .. && pwd'` works as suggested by @Charles Duffy above. Thanks!

Comment: The clear description of the process by @CharlesDuffy explains what really happens. If you could post it an an Answer here, others will also benefit from that. Thanks.

Comment: @mehdisharifi, ...I've added a set of links to duplicates (of other instances of the same question -- none of those using `gcloud ssh`, but all with the same underlying problem, and all with the same effective explanation).